# DATA SETS EN LISTAS - Agregar una columna

Tags: python-3.x

Soy nuevo en python y queria manejar una seria de data sets en listas para operaciones recurrente como agregar una columna con el año.  Este fue mi codigo:

for i in range(0, 11):
enaho[i]['YEAR'] = 2010+1

mas sin embargo, me da un error
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Me pueden ayudar a entender donde esta el error y como solucionarlo. Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Tiene que ser visible tu esfuerzo, acá no hacemos deberes, por favor añade tu código, lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), además te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: que tipo de dato hay ahi? sera un string, y tratas de pasarle un numero?